# How do I add a border on the table tag?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I am busy working with tables and for some reason the border property is not displaying in the browser.

I want to have a border on my table. I have even tried adding inline styles and it's not working for me.

I am using eclipse IDE for this code and I also have Java, HTML, CSS and Bootstrap

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    
<%@ page import="java.io.PrintWriter" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<!--This meta tag defines web pages size that can resize web pages depends on device screen size-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale="1">

<!--This link tag make this web site can use bootstrap's css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

<!--This title tag shows us about what kind of website is-->
<title>문제7 - 김준국</title>

<style>
  table {
    padding:5px;
    border: 1px solid #444444;
    
  }

  td {

    border: 1px solid #444444;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body> 

    <%
        String userID = null;
        if(session.getAttribute("userID") != null){
            userID = (String) session.getAttribute("userID");
        }
    %>
    <div>
        <input type='button' value='Back' onclick="location.href='assignments.jsp'"/>
        <h3>연습문제 7번입니다.</h3><br>

        <%
        String[][] strPerson = new String[4][3];
        
        strPerson[0][0] = "김갑수";
        strPerson[1][0] = "강문철";
        strPerson[2][0] = "신선영";
        strPerson[3][0] = "이명숙";
        strPerson[0][1] = "남";
        strPerson[1][1] = "남";
        strPerson[2][1] = "여";
        strPerson[3][1] = "여";
        strPerson[0][2] = "사장";
        strPerson[1][2] = "팀장";
        strPerson[2][2] = "부장";
        strPerson[3][2] = "사원";
         %>
        <table>
            <%
                for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            %>
            <tr>
                <%
                    for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
                %>
                <td align=center><%=strPerson[i][j]%></td>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </tr>

            <%
                }
            %>

        </table>
    </div>
    <!--Animation-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You probably don't need all the HTML boilerplace, can put the CSS into the CSS box in the live demo editor, and should include sample **HTML** instead of the JSP that generates it.

Comment: Also: The borders **show up** in the live demo you provided. When you supply code, make sure it actually demonstrates the problem!

Comment: Yip, borders are working fine as it should. You have a `<table>` tag and your css `table` declaration is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap, you can simply add `.table-bordered` class to the table and see the line around the table.

Bootstrap has prepared a number of classes for the table that are easy to use

Bootstrap `<table>` Document: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```